# How to get relation of belonging records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For example, I have posts and their authors. I need to do something like this:

```
SELECT users
  FROM posts
       LEFT JOIN users
       ON posts.user_id = users.id;
```

I know that it can be done like this:

```
@users = Post.all.collect do |post|
  post.user
end
```

But it return not `Relation` but `Array` and it is not effective I suppose.

Comment: Do you want to get user have at least one post? In the sql query, I saw you want to select `posts` but in ActiveRecord query, you collect users.

Comment: @taitrantuan it was a mistake, now it is correct. And no, user does not have to have a post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want users that have at least one post, you can use `joins`, something like that

```
User.joins(:posts).distinct
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It helps even if users don't have to have at least one post